# How to Remove excluding and including TaxMessage from Checkout Cart Summary Section in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

For Reference Check the Screenshot :- [image]

I have tried to override `checkout_cart_index.xml` inside `/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_Tax/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/subtotal</item>
        <item name="excludingTaxMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
        <item name="includingTaxMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
    </item>
</item>
```

and Removed **excludingTaxMessage** and **includingTaxMessage** text but it fetchs the text from **Core** module layout file after removing.

Please Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to set value as an empty string, try this way:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="excludingTaxMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">&#x200B;</item>
                                        <item name="includingTaxMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">&#x200B;</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is how it looking on my staging host:

[image: example view]

**PS**: the `&#x200B;` is zero-witdh space

Comment: It's working man......Thank you very much.

Comment: @VishalThakur I'm glad to help you. Please, accept my answer if it works.

Comment: can you please help me in one more thing - i want to Change Text of ' Subtotal (Incl. Tax) ' only not the ' Subtotal (Excl. Tax) '. and Move ' VAT(20%) ' section on 2nd place between ' Subtotal (Excl. Tax) ' and ' Subtotal (Incl. Tax) '. please help me .... See Screenshot in Question.

Comment: i have asked another question for that- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300710/how-to-change-text-and-sort-data-in-checkout-cart-summary-section-in-magento-2-3

please Help me ....!!!

Comment: @VishalThakur Seems you already found solution :)

Comment: yes i already found the solution.