# How to Change Text and Sort Data in Checkout Cart Summary Section in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

I want to Change Text of `Subtotal (Incl. Tax)` only not the `Subtotal (Excl. Tax)`. and Move `VAT(20%) or Tax` section on 2nd place between `Subtotal (Excl. Tax)` and `Subtotal (Incl. Tax)`. See Screenshot..

please help me ....

**First Image-**

[image]

**Second Image:-**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this after some R&D.

Need to add some code in Overrided layout file `checkout_cart_index.xml` and `checkout_index_index.xml`

> /app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_Tax/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
>
> /app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_Tax/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="firstTitle" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Base Price</item>
                                    <item name="secondTitle" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/subtotal</item>
                                    <item name="excludingTaxMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">&#x200B;</item>
                                    <item name="includingTaxMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">&#x200B;</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

and update the code in overrided Template file :-

> /app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/summary/subtotal.html

```
<tr class="totals sub excl override_totals_excl_tax">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <span data-bind="i18n: firstTitle"></span>
        <span data-bind="i18n: excludingTaxMessage"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': excludingTaxMessage}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="totals sub incl override_totals_incl_tax">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <span data-bind="i18n: secondTitle"></span>
        <span data-bind="i18n: includingTaxMessage"></span>
    </th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValueInclTax(), attr: {'data-th': includingTaxMessage}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```